# There is no such file error in global tool configuration in jenkins for git installation directory

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

Getting following error while trying to enter git installation path:

Path to Git executable

`C:\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core`

Error

`There's no such file: C:\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please copy&paste your error messages. And show more love when making screen shots...

Answer (score 0):

Git path should be in your case

`c:\Git\bin\git.exe`